# How can I flag a question that has an open bounty?

Tags: discussion

I came across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57074798/setting-up-jest-for-express) that based on my understanding of SO rules, is not in compliance.

Specifically, the post in question contains two questions that have distinct answers.  I proceed and try to flag the post, citing the reason as being 'overly broad', however, I received an red error message explaining that the post "has an open bounty and cannot be closed".

As a quick work-around, I left a polite comment asking the user to split the question.

Can someone explain how to flag an a question with an open bounty?  If this is not possible, **why not**?

Comment: Flag it for moderator attention explaining the situation. Moderators will see if the question is too broad and will remove the bounty (they have that ability). They will close the question shortly afterwards.